# table adapter weired returning value

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table adapter in Visual studio dataset. I aligned a value to the query inside the table adapter so I can get if the query returns 1 if there is data or 0 for null. example:

```
document.documentDataSetTableAdapters.Job_NoTableAdapter jnta = 
    new documentDataSetTableAdapters.Job_NoTableAdapter();

int result = jnta.FillBygetJob_No(documentDataSet1.Job_No);
```

It never happened to me that result get a value other than 0 or 1. here I got result = 2. so when I made the IF statement

```
if(result == 1){....}
else if(result == 0)
```

so I got the error. I solved the problem by doing this:

```
if(result == 0){...}
else{...}
```

So what I need is an explanation of how result got the value 2.

Comment: Have you attached a profiler to capture the query?

Comment: I suspect the answer is inside `jnta.FillBygetJob_No`, which you haven’t shown us.

Comment: What is your query for FillByGetJob_No?  What other properties does FillByGetJob_No method have?

Comment: I didn't use a profiler at all.

Comment: The query is like this:

SELECT JN_Full_Form, Job_No, Job_No_ID, year
FROM Job_No
WHERE (JN_Full_Form = (SELECT MAX(JN_Full_Form) AS Expr1
                               FROM Job_No AS Job_No_1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're filling a `DataSet` with this query(your comment):

```
SELECT JN_Full_Form, Job_No, Job_No_ID, year 
FROM Job_No 
WHERE (JN_Full_Form = (SELECT MAX(JN_Full_Form) AS Expr1 
                       FROM Job_No AS Job_No_1))
```

Now you expect that it always returns none or a single record. But what if there are two or more records with the same `JN_Full_Form` which are equal to `MAX(JN_Full_Form)`?!

So it's absolutely fine to change th `if`:

```
if(result == 0)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Another option is to change the query itself to select one record at a max(presuming sql-server):

```
SELECT TOP 1 JN_Full_Form, Job_No, Job_No_ID, year 
FROM Job_No 
WHERE (JN_Full_Form = (SELECT MAX(JN_Full_Form) AS Expr1 
                       FROM Job_No AS Job_No_1))
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, I looked after it and found that there is two records with the same JN_Full_Form. I appreciate your comment and thanks for the explanation